# Concerning Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, arithmetic-progressions

Let p and q be two consecutive prime numbers.

Let there be two arithmetic progressions whose initial terms differ by 2. Let both arithmetic progressions have the same common difference. Let the common difference be coprime to both p and q.

Within the first pq terms, will there be a place where the term of the first progression is a multiple of p and the term of the second progression is a multiple of q?

What proof is known?